# Address of a member in C structure

Tags: c, pointers

I have a code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    int *t;
    }C;


C *z;

z=(C*)malloc(sizeof(C));

z->x=4;
z->y=6;
z->t=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*(z->t) =10;
// Access value
printf("%d\n",*(z->t));

// Access address
printf("%d\n",z->t);

// Access value
printf("%f",z->x);

// Access address of z->x ?


free(z);

}
```

In the code I can access address and value of int *t but for float x I only know how to access the value using z->x , how can I access the address of z->x?

Comment: use &(z->x) to get address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `&` operator. Also, to print an address, you have to use the `%p` format specifier with `printf()`.

Worthy to mention<sup>1</sup>, `%p` expects an argument of type `void *`. As there may be some difference in the representation of a `void *` WRT `float *`, its better to cast the argument to `void *`.

So, altogether,

```
printf("%p",(void *)&(z->x));
```

Will give you the address of the member variable `x` in `z`.

<sup>1 : Thanks to Mr. pmg for the comment</sup>

Comment: The `"%p"` format specifier expects a `void*`. There may be differences between the representation of a void pointer and a pointer to float on some architectures: the value to be printed should be converted to type `void*` (for pedantics).

Comment: @pmg So a casting is required, right sir? Will update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `&` (address-of) operator

```
float *address = &(z->x); // maybe parenthesis are redundant
printf("addres of z->x is %p\n", (void*)address);
```